# Woocoomerce - add class to input tag

Tags: wordpress, input, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to add a custom class to input HTML tag at a checkout page in WooCoomerce.

For example: I want to add .smartform-zip to input with name billing_postcode and same thing with billing_adress_1 and city. How can I do? I try to write some hooks or customize some code on GitHub and nothing work.

I need it for autocomplete Czech service to customers address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will add the class to the  `<p>` tag which wraps the input element

```
    add_filter('woocommerce_form_field_args', function($args, $field, $value ){
        if( $field == 'billing_postcode' ) {
            $args['input_class'][] = 'smartform-zip';
        }
        if( $field == 'billing_address_1' ) {
            $args['input_class'][] = 'some-class';
        }
        return $args;
    },100, 3);
```

Comment: Thank you, but i need to add class to the <input> tag: 
What i need:
<input type="text" class="input-text smartform-zip " name="billing_postcode" id="billing_postcode" placeholder="" 1